Transactionn succeeded but dollars on wallet not updated?
I bought a meme coin and waited for it to go up once it did i swapped it back to solana and it showed as ot being a sucessful transaction even found my transaction on solscans but it hasnt updated in my wallet yet. Is there a reason?
